# How to save a picture that user uploaded to html page to sql server?

Tags: html, sql, web-services

in my sql database i have a column with image datatype, so i created a class in webService :

```
class Hazard
{
public string Hazard_ID { get; set; }
public DateTime Hazard_DateTime { get; set; }
public /*????*/ Hazard_Image { get; set; }
}
```

my question is about the type of the varible Hazard_Image what it have to be?

this is the client side below:

```
<input type="file" id="APHazardPicture" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

Comment: A simple search for file inputs could give you your answer

Comment: i searched, what i found is an example to my question but not from html, it was from windows form appliction and asp

Comment: Are you saying you want to know the data type for the variable which interacts with web forms?

Comment: yes, and if you could help me by telling me what to do step by step i'll be happy for this

Comment: `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Alright. Last question. Which framework are you using? and what language?

Comment: In case you are using servlets [this link](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/eclipse-file-upload-servlet-with-apache-common-file-upload) could help you out